# Is it possible to protect a region of memory from WinAPI?

Tags: c++, winapi, memory-management, heap-corruption

Having read [this interesting article](http://www.rt-embedded.com/blog/archives/resolving-memory-corruption/) outlining a technique for debugging heap corruption, I started wondering how I could tweak it for my own needs. The basic idea is to provide a custom malloc() for allocating whole pages of memory, then enabling some memory protection bits for those pages, so that the program crashes when they get written to, and the offending write instruction can be caught in the act. The sample code is C under Linux (mprotect() is used to enable the protection), and I'm curious as to how to apply this to native C++ and Windows. VirtualAlloc() and/or VirtualProtect() look promising, but I'm not sure how a use scenario would look like.

```
Fred *p = new Fred[100];
ProtectBuffer(p);
p[10] = Fred(); // like this to crash please
```

I am aware of the existence of specialized tools for debugging memory corruption in Windows, but I'm still curious if it would be possible to do it "manually" using this approach.

**EDIT:** Also, is this even a good idea under Windows, or just an entertaining intellectual excercise?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can use VirtualAlloc and VirtualProtect to set up sections of memory that are protected from read/write operations.

You would have to re-implement `operator new` and `operator delete`  (and their [] relatives), such that your memory allocations are controlled by your code.

And bear in mind that it would only be on a per-page basis, and you would be using (at least) three pages worth of virtual memory per allocation - not a huge problem on a 64-bit system, but may cause problems if you have many allocations in a 32-bit system.

Roughly what you need to do (you should actually find the page-size for the build of Windows - I'm too lazy, so I'll use 4096 and 4095 to represent pagesize and pagesize-1 - you also will need to do more error checking than this code does!!!):

```
void *operator new(size_t size)
{
    Round size up to size in pages + 2 pages extra.
    size_t bigsize = (size + 2*4096 + 4095) & ~4095; 

    // Make a reservation of "size" bytes. 
    void *addr = VirtualAlloc(NULL, bigsize, PAGE_NOACCESS, MEM_RESERVE);

    addr = reinterpret_cast<void *>(reinterpret_cast<char *>(addr) + 4096);

    void *new_addr = VirtualAlloc(addr, size, PAGE_READWRITE, MEM_COMMIT); 

    return new_addr;
}

void operator delete(void *ptr)
{
    char *tmp = reinterpret_cast<char *>(ptr) - 4096;

    VirtualFree(reinterpret_cast<void*>(tmp)); 
}
```

Something along those lines, as I said - I haven't tried compiling this code, as I only have a Windows VM, and I can't be bothered to download a compiler and see if it actually compiles. [I know the principle works, as we did something similar where I worked a few years back].

Comment: I especially like the `reinterpret_cats` part ;)

Comment: Well, it is C++, and you can't add things to void pointers according to the standard... ;) Ehm, I see what you mean now - it's late, I should have gone to bed long before I started writing that, really....

Comment: I don't get it; why the two VirtualAlloc's?

Comment: First one reserves a region of (say) 12KB, with no access using MEM_RESERVE - the second populates it with REAL memory (MEM_COMMIT) so you can actually write to it. This presumes you actually want to use the memory "in the middle". The basic idea is you get one page on either side of the actual memory.

Comment: Okay, so I still have to use VirtualProtect on the address returned from this implementation of new?

Comment: I don't think so, but like I said, I haven't tried this code, so it may not work... I would start by implementing the above two functions as a "myalloc" and "myfree", and see if you can allocate/free memory, and that accessing outside the page(s) that you are supposed to access provides the relevant crash.

Comment: Okay, so I'm guessing VirtualProtect is used to enable protection on pages which were alloc'd without PAGE_NOACCESS? Also, what did you guys mean about the reinterpret_cast?

Answer (score 2):

This is what Gaurd Pages are for (see this [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366549%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) tutorial), they raise a special exception when the page is accessed the first time, allowing you to do more than crash on the first invalid pages access (and catch bad read/writes as opposed to NULL pointers etc).

Comment: Out of curiosity, have you ever tried this and can confirm that it's working reliably? I seem to remember that Windows itself uses guard pages to commmit pages for the stack beyond the minimum commit size. So, firing and handling guard page faults might interfere with normal operation?

Comment: @Damon: I haven't used guard pages myself, purely because I haven't needed them, but I've seen a few system that use this to catch unauthorized access for external programs. And beyond that, your programs exception handler would only receive the guard page exceptions for the memory *you* guard (if by some stupidity windows passes you its guard exceptions, you can easily filter this out by inspecting the address).